# Mongoose - Populating a nested array of objects not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a collection called Orders that contains this schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    restaurant: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Restaurant',
        required: true
    },
    dishes: [
        {
            dish: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Dish'
            },
            amount: Number
        }
    ],
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['PROCESSING', 'CANCELLED', 'COMPLETED', 'ERROR'],
        default: 'PROCESSING'
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

Inside my router, I have this code:

```
let orders = await Order.find({restaurant: restaurantID, status:'PROCESSING'}).populate('dishes._id').exec()
```

Order.find does not throw an exception, but it isnt working either.
I want the res.body to look like this:

```
            {
                "_id": "objectID",
                "user": "objectID",
                "restaurant": "objectID",
                "dishes": [
                    {
                        "amount": number,
                        "dish": {
                            //dish object
                        }
                    },
                    ...
                ],
                //other order properties
            },
            ...
        ]
```

But for some reason the `dishes` array looks like this:

```
        "dishes": [
            {
                "amount": 1,
                "_id": "6184e848e6d1974a0569783d"
            }
        ],
```

What am I doing wrong?

I know that if `populate()` worked the res.body `dishes` array would not have a property called 'dish' and instead have a property called `_id` that would contain the dish object, but this shouldnt be hard to change once `populate()` works.

EDIT:

I realised that my createOrder route could be part of the problem since it ignores my schema and uses an `id` property for the objectID instead of `dish`. The array I save to the DB contains a property called `id` for the id instead of `dish`, but shouldnt my schema throw an exception when i try to save something like this to my database?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I think the problem might be that you have a syntax problem.
Try

```
.populate('dishes').exec()
```

instead of

```
.populate('dishes._id').exec()
```

Comment: Wouldnt that overwrite my `amount` property, too, and only save the dish object inside the array?

Comment: Don't think so, just try it

Comment: doesn't work, the res.body still looks the same